# Can imacros clear ALL history, cache , cookies and data browser

Tags: php, bots, imacros

Is there a way to clear all cache and cookies (equivalent of pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> in firefox and selecting every checkbox) using imacros?

I know about the `CLEAR` command but I have found that it doesn't clear everything.

Comment: do you solve this problem i have it now :s